# CSS - how to render buttons on top of a background image?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, button, background-image

Hello Stack Overflow,

I'm currently working on building a component that will have a background-image, and on this background-image I want to render buttons exactly over a certain section of the background image. My intention is to make this resizeable - the buttons should stay over a certain area despite the aspect ratio.

This is what it looks like with standard layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rt6u1.jpg

This is what it looks like if I play with the aspect ratio: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBeWf.jpg

Edit: This is a link to a codesandbox which has a rendition of the latest design I was working with: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-rgb-do24t.

Is it possible that whenever I resize the aspect ratio of the page, I will still have those buttons over the certain area of the background image? If I resize the window, I notice that the buttons will fly off the background image. I've attached my code below.

Application:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Home.css'

class Home extends Component    {
    render()    {
        return (
           <div className="container">
                <div className="box-one">
                    <button className="button"> Image One </button>
                    <button className="button2"> Image Two </button>
                </div>
           </div>
        );
    }
}
 
export default Home;
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  background-image: url(../components/space_wallpaper.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  left: 10vw;
  top: 10vh;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vw;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}

.box-one {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 1% 1%;
}

.button2  {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 50% 50%;
}
```

Comment: try background-size: cover;

Comment: hi Chandradeepta,
I tried that, and I discovered that any button that I would have on the bottom would disappear/leave the background-image when I resize. I can use cover, but I have to then ensure that the buttons don't leave the container component.

Comment: I have answered below. Please have a look. If you want something specific, please let me know.

Comment: it would be better (if this answer is not what you are looking for), to post a codesandbox in order to test it.

Comment: @Apostolos, sounds good. This is the link to a codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-rgb-do24t

Comment: so what you need is that when background image changes size due to resizing of window, these buttons to be displayed at specific part of image as initially? hmm sounds difficult

Comment: @Apostolos yes exactly, I'm actually unsure if it's even possible, but I just recently started playing with CSS so I'm unsure if that's true. They don't have to be so precisely exact, but I would at least prefer it so that the buttons don't fly off the background-image - maybe limit resizing so that the background-image doesn't shrink?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
.container {
  background-image: url(../components/space_wallpaper.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  left: 10vw;
  top: 10vh;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vw;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}

.box-one {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Hey Chandradeepta, 

This is not quite what I was looking for but I believe it's closer to the end goal.

I think having a backgroud-size that is cover is good. What I'm doing now is that in each of my buttons, I am setting their position as absolute.  I am using your rendition of the CSS for box-one. The issue I'm having now is that if there are any buttons that are on the bottom, and if I shrink the page, those buttons will leave my component. Check out this Imgur link: https://imgur.com/a/WKidvLm and this codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-rgb-do24t

Comment: Have a look at this https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-babbage-iyp6c?file=/src/App.css

Comment: Don't use the position as absolute. Instead, use the container as a flexbox and the buttons as flex items. So you can control their behavior as you want

Comment: Chandradeepta, thanks for your help! I was wondering if it's possible to map multiple buttons at a specific spot doing it the way you did. For instance, how can I position the "Image Two" button about 10px down and to the right of the first button (Image One)?

Comment: in .box-one class remove the justify-content property. and add .button2 styles as .button2 {
  align-self: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-babbage-iyp6c?file=/src/App.css:368-422

Comment: hey Chandradeepta, thanks for helping! I tried the sandbox and unfortunately if you position the button along the bottom (set margin-top to another value along the bottom of the container) the button will leave the frame. I'm starting to think that what I am trying to accomplish might be impossible.

Comment: I couldn't understand what is your expected output !

Comment: when background image changes size due to resizing of window, the buttons are to be displayed at specific part of image as when initially sized.

Comment: And where do you want the buttons exactly?

Comment: if you looked on the imgur link (https://imgur.com/a/IzKLUI7) I have 10 space images - I want a button on each of those 10 images (10 total buttons) that even when I resize the window, the button over one of the space images (between the boundaries) doesn't flow into the next image.

Comment: In order to do that, you need to fix your container. use min-width and min-height. So your container won't move. All you'll get is the vertical and horizontal scrolling